# iOS/iPadOS - What is being transferred when migrating to the new device / can we detect migration?

Tags: ios, xcode, migration, nsuserdefaults

Imagine developing an app for iOS. App stores data to the UserDefaults.

User has the app installed on device A then buys a new device B. On device launch he chooses to transfer/migrate all data from device A to device B. Once this is done, he runs the app on device B.

1. does device B have UserDefaults transferred too?
2. if so, can you detect on app start that this is the first start on different device after this transfer/migration?